# Call to a member function getClientOriginalName() on null

Tags: php, laravel, amazon-s3, image-uploading

I can upload my file using to amazon s3 bucket successfully using my api and i can get a response:

But when i integrate this api into my application it says Call to a member function getClientOriginalName() on null i dont know where i am doing wrong:

My Api method:

```
public function uploadToAws(Request $request) {
    $file = $request->file('image');
    $imageName = 'company_logo/' . $file->getClientOriginalName();
    Storage::disk('s3')->put($imageName, file_get_contents($file));
    Storage::disk('s3')->setVisibility($imageName, 'public');
    $url = Storage::disk('s3')->url($imageName);
    $resultArray = ['status' => 1, 'message' => 'File uploaded to s3 bucket!', 'dataArray' => $url];

    return Response::json($resultArray, 200);
}
```

and my response of this api:

```
{
    "status": 1,
    "message": "File uploaded to s3 bucket!",
    "dataArray": "https://spikessales.s3.amazonaws.com/company_logo/template3.jpg"
}
```

I can perfectly upload file to s3 bucket using this api:

But when i integrate to my application view it says Call to a member function getClientOriginalName() on null i dont where i am wrong:

This view code using ajax call:

```
       ///upload logo sec
     $(document).on('click', '.browse', function () {
   var file = $(this).parent().parent().parent().find('.changefle');
   file.trigger('click');

  });
   $(document).on('change', '.changefle', function () {
    var imagename = "";

    $.each($(".changefle")[0].files, function (i, file) {
    imagename = file.name;

});
    $.ajax({//Process the form using $.ajax()
    type: 'post', //Method type
    url: 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/upload_aws', //Your form processing file 
     URL
    data: {
        image: imagename
    }, //Forms name
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function (data) {
        console.log(data);
        // localStorage.setItem("set-compylogo", companylogo);
       },
       error: function (data) {

           console.log("error");
       }
```

Your help will be highly appreciated!

Comment: i think in your form files is true is not available.

Comment: i dont know about view files the other man is integrating my api

Comment: $request->file('image'); is may be null

Comment: Any solution please

Comment: if ($request->hasFile('image')) { } try to put condition and check

Comment: dd($file); show your result

Comment: when i dd i can show my image which i have uploaded

Comment: 500 (Internal Server Error)

Comment: it showing this :(

Comment: you can not upload image file directly via simple ajax.try ajaxSubmit() method instead.

Answer (score 0):

It might be your ajax need more headers to upload file. or may be it need this:

```
$.ajax({
    headers: {
        'X-CSRF-TOKEN': your_crsf_token,
        'Content-type: text/html;charset=ISO-8859-1'
    },
    ...
});
```

For further information, you might want to check this out: [AJAX File Upload with XMLHttpRequest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10475313/ajax-file-upload-with-xmlhttprequest)

Answer (score 0):

You are sending a string (image name) instead of a FILE object. To use those methods laravel needs a file object. So `imagename = file;` instead of `imagename = file.name`

Comment: add  contentType: 'multipart/form-data' to your ajax call and probably you have to remove dataType: 'json'

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Illegal invocation
    at o (jquery.js:6)
    at gn (jquery.js:6)
    at gn (jquery.js:6)
    at Function.x.param (jquery.js:6)
    at Function.ajax (jquery.js:6)
    at HTMLInputElement.<anonymous> (custom-script.js:392)
    at HTMLDocument.dispatch (jquery.js:5)
    at HTMLDocument.v.handle (jquery.js:5)

Comment: this is response